# Select a row and then more rows based on a value in that row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table called myTable and I would like to select all rows in which B = DFW, and also all rows in which B = the value of C when B = DFW.

This is what I have so far but for some reason it only returns rows where B = DFW:

```
SELECT * from myTable AS t1 WHERE EXISTS (
 SELECT C AS c_val from myTable WHERE t1.B="DFW" or (t1.B="DFW" and t1.C=c_val)
)
```

It should return the row where B = DFW, and where B = DTW as per what I said above.

[image]

Comment: Could you please give the complete description of which rows you expect?
The way I understand this is you would like to select `all rows where B = DFW` plus `all rows where B = DFW and C = DFW` but this does not match with your expectation to retrieve rows where `C = DTW`. If my understanding is correct I would just do this `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE B='DFW' UNION SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE B='DFW' AND C='DFW'`

Comment: No the ask is to B= DFW, and then B = any of the values of C when B=DFW

Comment: `B = any of the values of C when B=DFW`: when `B=DFW` and if `B=C` then `C=DFW`... isn't it? Could you give the row numbers you want to retrieve?

Comment: Rows 3 and 8 in this example

Comment: B = DFW, look at the values that C is when B=DFW. Now for each of these values of C, select that row's who's B = any of these values of C

Comment: OK got it! The answer of Shawn below with the CTE looks good then...

Comment: The way how the question is worded is poor. The initial comment from Alexis.Rolland is what everyone who reads the question would assume. Please reword the question so it's clearer to a reader.

Answer (score 2):

A [UNION](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) with a CTE is one way:

```
WITH dfws(a, b, c) AS (SELECT a, b, c FROM myTable WHERE b = 'DFW')
SELECT a, b, c FROM dfws
UNION
SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c
FROM myTable AS t
JOIN dfws AS d ON t.b = d.c;
```

Basically, you use a *CTE* ([Common Table Expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html), kind of like a view that's local to a single query) to define `dfws` as all the rows where `b` is 'DFW'. You then return those rows, as well as the results of an inner join of `dfws` against your original full table on the rows where `b` equals `dfws.c`.

Edit: 
Another option is to use the `IN` operator:

```
SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c
FROM mytable AS t
WHERE t.b = 'DFW' OR t.b IN (SELECT t2.c FROM mytable AS t2 WHERE t2.b = 'DFW');
```

After a quick glance at the respective query plans, I'm not sure which would be more efficient when dealing with big tables.

For best results with either you'll want an index on column b, though.

Comment: I like the `in` version.

Answer (score 0):

I like the `IN` version in Shawn's answer.

Generally, one can rewrite `IN` expressions to an expression involving `EXISTS`. I will cover both versions here and explain the differences.

Firstly, some preamble, here's the DDL for your dataset:

```sql
drop table if exists myTable;

create table myTable (A text, B text, C text);
insert into myTable values ('WN', 'HOU', 'TUL');
insert into myTable values ('AA', 'MCO', 'ORD');
insert into myTable values ('AA', 'DFW', 'DTW');
insert into myTable values ('AA', 'ORD', 'DFW');
insert into myTable values ('F9', 'MCO', 'DTW');
insert into myTable values ('UA', 'LAS', 'LAX');
insert into myTable values ('WN', 'PHX', 'OAK');
insert into myTable values ('OO', 'DTW', 'ESC');
insert into myTable values ('AA', 'LGA', 'DCA');
insert into myTable values ('AA', 'LAX', 'DFW');

create index ix_myTable_001 on myTable (b);
create index ix_myTable_002 on myTable (c);
```

Here's the `IN` version of the query along with it's execution plan:

```sql
SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c
FROM mytable AS t
WHERE t.b = 'DFW' OR t.b IN (SELECT t2.c FROM mytable AS t2 WHERE t2.b = 'DFW');

explain query plan
SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c
FROM mytable AS t
WHERE t.b = 'DFW' OR t.b IN (SELECT t2.c FROM mytable AS t2 WHERE t2.b = 'DFW');

AA|DFW|DTW
OO|DTW|ESC

0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE mytable AS t USING INDEX ix_myTable_001 (b=?)
0|0|0|EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 1
1|0|0|SEARCH TABLE mytable AS t2 USING INDEX ix_myTable_001 (b=?)
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE mytable AS t USING INDEX ix_myTable_001 (b=?)
```

Here is the `EXISTS` version of the query:

```sql
select * from myTable T1
where T1.b = 'DFW' OR exists (
SELECT 1
FROM myTable T2
WHERE T2.B = 'DFW'
AND T1.B = T2.C);

explain query plan
select * from myTable T1
where T1.b = 'DFW' OR exists (
SELECT 1
FROM myTable T2
WHERE T2.B = 'DFW'
AND T1.B = T2.C);

AA|DFW|DTW
OO|DTW|ESC

0|0|0|SCAN TABLE myTable AS T1
0|0|0|EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
1|0|0|SEARCH TABLE myTable AS T2 USING INDEX ix_myTable_002 (c=?)
```

Summarizing: `IN` expressions forces the subquery to be fully evaluated first before the outer query executes. `EXISTS` expressions sometimes both the outer query and the subquery can be evaluated concurrently. This means more flexibility in the execution and potentially savings in execution and memory usage.

Deciding on whether you choose the `IN` version vs the `EXISTS` version is whether the subquery would generate a small or large result. If it's small go for the `IN` version. If it's large, then go for the `EXISTS` version.

Comment: In the exists, how come you only SELECT 1?

Comment: @rapto500134 when using EXISTS for the subquery, only the WHERE clause is important. The SELECT portion is not used, so, whatever you put there will be thrown away. Usually people use `SELECT *` which infers we're retrieving columns for the subquery. In fact, we're not, so, I just default to the scalar constant 1 which allows the optimizer to focus on the WHERE clause.